# Using package entry points with pyproject.toml based editable installs

Tags: pip, setuptools

My entry points are setup like this

```
[options]
package_dir =
    = package
packages = .
python_requires = >=3.6

[option.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    cons = scripts.cons

gui_scripts =
    gui = scripts.gui
```

I installed the package in editable mode with `pip install -e .`. I can import `package` through a Python REPL, but running `cons` or `gui` (these are not the real names) doesn't work. I found that the entry point scripts are indeed not placed in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts` but `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\package.egg-link` does exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `setuptools`, this is because you installed the package in editable mode, and then tried to run it from the CLI. To use the command from the CLI, you may NOT install it in editable mode. Instead just use:

> pip install .

Using `flit` allows for editable CLI installs.

Comment: I figured it out long back, plus now I use `venv` that's much safer and isolated, thanks anyways tho!

Comment: Maybe make this a accepted answer then ? @demberto

Comment: What is `flit`? And how do I solve that problem in `--editable` mode.

Comment: 'A simple packaging tool for simple packages.', https://pypi.org/project/flit/
@buhtz what command are you using to install? If you are using 'pip install -e .', you should instead use 'pip install .'